# C++ dynamically assign headers

Tags: c++, header-files, dynamically-generated

I would like to implement multi application that share with each other the main (or in general, we could say a `.cpp` file).

Let me explain. Given a dir structure something like this:

```
 - main.cpp
 -- app1
 --- app1.cpp
 --- app1.h
 -- app2
 --- app2.cpp
 --- app2.h
 -- ...
```

I would like to compile N app with the same `main.cpp`, but with different header. Lets say, something like this:

```
app1 := main.cpp + app1.cpp
app2 := main.cpp + app2.cpp
```

As a pseudocode, the `main.cpp` should be look like this, but I don't know how can I assign dinamically the header:

```
# main.cpp
foreach sub_dir
  # create a main with only the headers in this subdir
  foreach headers_in_subdirs
   <include "sub_dir/header.h">
  end

# rest of the main omitted
```

A possible solution is to copy the `main.cpp` in each subdirs, but in this way the code is not maintainable. Regroup all the subapp in a big one is unfortunately not possible for the app purpose.

The compilation side is not a problem (I do it with singles commands query in a `makefile`), but the question is: **how can I dynamically assign headers**?

Comment: would running a tool like this in each subdir help? (i've not used it) http://www.hwaci.com/sw/mkhdr/makeheaders.html

Comment: good point @Jimmy, this tool has given my an idea. What do you think about playing with ```#ifdefine ... include libs .. #elseif ...``` in the ```main.cpp``` and then define an unique variable in each subdirs. What do you think, should it work?

Comment: think that is essentially one of your answers below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a pre-defined macro to the compiler to choose which headers to include:

```
#if APP == 1
#include "something_1"
#include "something_else_1"
#elif APP == 2
#include "something_2"
#include "something_else_2"
#else
#error No such app
#endif
```

Or, if you gather the desired headers under one file, you can pre-define the name of the header itself.

Comment: +1 thank you @user2079303 I have followed your solution!

Answer (score 1):

Number of possible solutions here, so you need to choose something that you like more, objective analysis is quite difficult in this case. I would do something like this:

Make your main application-agnostic, e.g.

```
# main.cpp
<include "header.h">
# rest of the main omitted
```

Put different versions of "header.h" files into each subdir. Now generate (part of) makefile by specifying application-specific settings like which .cpp files to compile and what is include directory ("app1", "app2" and so on) so compiler can find corresponding "header.h". Can be done by Bash or Python or whatever else. Or just hardcode makefile if your application set is stable.

Comment: +1 if I could accept two solution I will accept even yours, I think that this way is another cool option to solve my problem (but when I have tried your solution, I have faced at the "missing header" mistery ;) ). Anyway thanks!